# Convert Is_date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

How to convert the below two oracle statements in sql

```
IS_DATE(pInputDate || '01', 'YYMMDD') = 'Y'

TO_DATE('19' || pInputDate || '01', 'YYYYMMDD');
```

I tried IsDate function and 
CONVERT(ISNULL(DATETIME, pInputDate , '') + '01', 'YYMMDD') but its not working it out.

Comment: What would pInputDate  look like?

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have?  2008+ has `IsDate()`

Comment: pInputDate  LOOK LIKE '1899'

Comment: `IS_DATE` is not a Oracle function

Answer (score 3):

For the first:

```
try_convert(date, '19' + pInputDate + '01') is not null
```

(The "19" is not strictly necessary, but it does check for a two digit year.)

For the second:

```
try_convert(date,  '19' + pInputDate + '01')
```

(Note:  This assumes that `pInputDate` is in the format YYMM -- based on the YYYYMMDD character format.)

`try_convert()` is available in SQL Server 2012+.  All versions of SQL Server recognize strings in the format of YYYYMMDD as dates.

For SQL Server 2008, you don't have `try_convert()`.  `isdate()` may help:

```
isdate('19' + pInputDate + '01') = 1
```

For the second:

```
convert(date,  '19' + pInputDate + '01')
```

This doesn't catch errors, so it is not as safe as `try_convert()`.

Comment: Plus1 for deducing what pInputDate looks like

Comment: awe come on that was spelled out! `pInputDate || '01', 'YYMMDD'` must mean that it's YYMM! :P

Comment: Hi thank you for this. I got error 'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @xQbert  I didn't see it.   I never think of years as YY.  When Gordon posted his answer, only then did I have the "Ah-ha" moment

Comment: This answer is not helped me since  'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name when I execute this

Comment: isdate() function will work fine for the second one since it has(yyyymmdd) format. What about the format for yymmdd for the first one.